# Question about why logarithm is a non-isolated singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this paragraph about why log(z)has a non-isolated singularity at zero:
[image: page1]

I don't understand how I might convince myself of this, from the above statement. I already know, that log(z) has a branch point at zero, because it is multivalued.

But on the other hand, if I use the above definition, if I choose say $r=\epsilon$, centered at zero, then $log z = log |\epsilon| -i\pi$ for some z on the negative real axis. I am not sure how to proceed next to prove it.

Comment: What's the definition of Log?

Comment: You can't define the logarithm as an analytic function – not even as a *continuous* function – on a punctured disk around the origin. If it's not analytic in a punctured disk, then it doesn't have an isolated singularity.

Comment: $Log (z) = Log |r| + i\theta$

Comment: That makes sense @GerryMyerson. I guess I was trying to find a way to prove, for other points around the center.